# How to set a timeout for a simple instruction?

Tags: android, textview

I want to set my textview to have a string, then, after some seconds i want to set another string to it. Is it possible with Android? Thank you very much.
This is what i want to do:

```
wtActivity2.updateStatus("Call rejected");
//timeout 5 seconds
wtActivity2.updateStatus("Ready.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, actually:

```
final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
textView.setText("Call rejected");
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Ready.");
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I have the function updateStatus that changes the textview! Can i make this with updateStatus function ? Thank you.